# Using Activity methods in Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-fragments, android-activity

Hi I am an amateur in Android, and I've got huge problem with using activity methods in my fragment class.

I would like to implement `setContentView`, `findViewById` and `getMenuInflater`. Unfortunately, I don't know how to do it.

```
public class WagaFragment extends Fragment{

    private Spinner fromSpinner, toSpinner;
    private EditText fromEditText, toEditText;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        **setContentView**(R.layout.activity_main);


        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.units, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

        fromSpinner = (Spinner) **findViewById**(R.id.spinner_from);
        toSpinner = (Spinner) **findViewById**(R.id.spinner_to);

        fromSpinner.setAdapter(adapter);
        toSpinner.setAdapter(adapter);

        fromEditText = (EditText) **findViewById**(R.id.editText_from);
        toEditText = (EditText) **findViewById**(R.id.editText_to);


        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        toolbar.setTitle(R.string.app_name);
        toolbar.setTitleTextColor(Color.YELLOW);


    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        **getMenuInflater()**.inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public void konwertuj(View view) {
        // Get the string from the Spinners and number from the EditText
        String fromString = (String) fromSpinner.getSelectedItem();
        String toString = (String) toSpinner.getSelectedItem();
        double input = Double.valueOf(fromEditText.getText().toString());

        // Convert the strings to something in our Unit enu,
        Konwerter.Jednostka fromJednostka = Konwerter.Jednostka.fromString(fromString);
        Konwerter.Jednostka toJednostka = Konwerter.Jednostka.fromString(toString);

        // Create a converter object and convert!
        Konwerter konwerter = new Konwerter(fromJednostka, toJednostka);
        double result = konwerter.convert(input);
        toEditText.setText(String.valueOf(result));
    }
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_fragment_1, container, false);

    }

}
```

Comment: You have to go back to the fundamentals of fragments. That's not how you create and inflate a fragment and to access some Activity methods you can use getActivity()

Comment: You shouldn't be using activity's methods in your fragments while you're designing them. You should instead design your fragment as a standalone box having a standard and predefined interface with its parent activity. A fragment shouldn't break its boundaries, for example fragments shouldn't use `setContentView` of their fragments. A fragment must only be responsible for its own view _not_ those of its parent activity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Fragments "contentView" (in your meanign) is defined in `public View onCreateView` procedure.

According to your code:
you have to use

```
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_fragment_1, container, false);
<your control> = <Control type> view.findViewById(<control id>)
```

For MenuInflater try this:

```
MenuInflater inflater = getActivity().getMenuInflater();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try at onCreateView:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
  Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_name, container, false);
    fromSpinner = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.spinner_from);
    return view;
  }
```